# Determining the Discrete Fourier Transformation of signal.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm studying signal analysis and now I'm at the Fourier series/transformations.

I'm following an example but can't understand the last step.

This problem is divided in two steps.

**FIRST**

From this Fourier Transformation (FT)

[image]

I have to show the expression of the Discrete Time Fourier Transformation (DTFT) and from what frequency I can reconstruct the signal without aliasing.
This is done this way:
[image]
[image]

I can understand all of these steps so no problem here.

**SECOND**
I have to determine the Discrete Fourier Transformation (DFT) assuming $f_s=50Hz$ and that the DFT assumes a window with $500$ samples. This is done this way:
[image]

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
I can't understand the red dotted square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that  happens in the red dotted square  is plugging $f_s=50$ and $\omega=k \pi/5$ into the formula for $X_{DTFT}$ written above. It should be noted that $X_{DTFT}$ is periodic with period $\omega_s=2\pi f_s=100\pi$, and the formula we have for it is written in terms of $\omega- k\omega_s$. This means  we sometimes have to subtract an appropriate multiple of the period from $\omega$ to place the difference  $\omega- k\omega_s$ into a range where the formula applies.

- If $0\le k\le 200$, then $0\le \omega\le 40\pi$, hence $X_{DTFT}(\omega)=f_s(40\pi -\omega)= 50(40\pi - k\pi/5)$.
- If $300\le k< 500$, then $60\pi \le \omega<100\pi$, which can also be written as $-40\pi \le \omega-100\pi <0$. Hence $X_{DTFT}(\omega)=f_s(\omega-100\pi+40\pi)= 50( k\pi/5-60\pi)$.
- If $200< k< 300$, then $40\pi< \omega< 60\pi$ (the second inequality is also $\omega-100\pi<-40\pi$), hence $X_{DTFT}(\omega)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Just didn't understand the bullet part.how come I go from $0<k<200$ to $0<\omega<40\pi$?

Comment: @Favolas Because $\omega=k\pi/5$, and $200\pi/5 = 40\pi$.

Comment: Thanks but I still dont get the steps. Shouldn't I go from the ranges of $\omega$ to $k$?

Comment: From $0\le k\le 200$,   multiplying all terms by $\pi/5$, we arrive at $0\cdot \pi/5\le k\cdot \pi/5<200\cdot \pi/5$. Which simplifies to $0\le \omega\le  40\pi$.

Comment: Yes. I understand that but my for that I must know that the range is $0<k<200$ How does those 3 ranges (in terms of $k$) came from?

Comment: @Favolas From the corresponding ranges in the formula for $X_{DTFT}(\omega)$. The ranges were separated by $-40\pi,0,40\pi$ (plus multiples of $\omega_s$, by periodicity). In terms of $k$ these would be $-200,0,200$ (divide by $\pi/5$). Because the period of $X_{DTFT}(k\pi/5)$ in terms of $k$ is $100\pi/(\pi/5)=500$, the transition at $k=-200$ also occurs at $k=300$. By periodicity, the function can be described on the interval $[0,500]$, with transition points at $200$ and $300$.

Comment: Ok.Many thanks. I now understand